# Unable to delete feature content type after uninstalling feature

Tags: 7, nodes, features

### Issue

Uninstalling a feature which creates a content type hides the "Delete" link on the `admin/structure/types`.

[Issue on Drupal.org](http://drupal.org/node/1055460)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Solution

Using a `hook_uninstall()` in FEATURE_NAME.install file and changing the status of the content type, so the system thinks it is an unlocked, custom content type.

[I posted this also on d.org](http://drupal.org/node/1055460#comment-6511334).

```
<?php
/**
 * Implements hook_uninstall().
 */
function FEATURE_NAME_uninstall() {

  // List custom content types added by this feature
  $custom_ctypes = array(
    'blog',
  );

  // Go through each and unlock the content type
  foreach ($custom_ctypes as $ctype) {
    db_query("UPDATE {node_type} SET `custom` = 1, locked = 0 WHERE type = :ctype", array(':ctype' => $ctype));
  }

  // Clean Drupal cache; this is necessary for the "Delete" link to appear
  // next to the content type created by the feature.
  drupal_flush_all_caches();

}
```

This will make the "Delete" button appear for that content type, so you can delete it from the admin.

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: To clarify, this does not delete the content type; it makes the 'delete' link available in the content type listing page.  Thanks @Ivanhoe123!

Comment: Also, I was not able to do this while my features module was enabled, but after disabling & uninstalling (I used drush) this worked beautifully.  Shortcut: use the devel module by dropping the contents of this function into /devel/php.  To programmatically delete content type add `node_type_delete($ctype); ` after the query in the for loop.

Comment: Thanks for that code. After seeing this code i edited my database using phpMyAdmin and edited the "node_type" table. Then i found the contect type i waned to delete and set the "Custom" value to "1". And finnaly i deleted it from the Drupal Administration.

Comment: `mysql> UPDATE node_type SET custom = 1, locked = 0 WHERE type = '<content type machine name>';`

Comment: @MarcoLazzeri's solution worked perfectly for me and was a lot better than having to update my feature module just to uninstall it.

Comment: Thanks, @MarcoLazzeri. Running that query followed by deleting the feature-installed content type in the admin helped.

Comment: Do not use db_query for INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE queries. Those should be handled via db_insert(), db_update() and db_delete() respectively.
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database%21database.inc/7.x

Comment: @MarcelCozma yes, I could use `db_update()`; however don't think that those functions should be used literally everywhere instead of `db_query()`. On small examples like this it doesn't matter which one is used; furthermore the `db_query()` is faster so in certain cases you should actually use it instead of alternatives to make things more optimized. You can see this used throughout the D7 core and core modules.

Answer (score 12):

For me, the solution was to load the delete page manually since there is no "delete" link on the content types page. To do this, you just need to construct the URL yourself by following the same URL structure as the delete page for other content types:

admin/structure/types/manage/YOUR_CONTENT_TYPE_MACHINE_NAME/delete

This brought up the content type delete confirmation page, which then allowed me to delete the content type.

For reference, see this thread on Drupal.org:

https://drupal.org/node/1055460#comment-7297680

Regards,

@cmsdave

Comment: I just changed the display content type link at the end to delete and could remove the content type without a problem. This solution works!

Comment: **Note**: Before this would work I had to edit the feature's `.info` file and remove the content type, then it would actually delete.

Answer (score 3):

The above method does not delete taxonomies, but this can be achieved by appending the following after disabling and uninstalling the module:

```
// Delete taxonomies.
$machine_names = array('taxonomy_a', 'taxonomy_b');
foreach ($machine_names as $machine_name) {
  $taxonomy = taxonomy_vocabulary_machine_name_load($machine_name);
  taxonomy_vocabulary_delete($taxonomy->vid);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution that worked for me directly to the database in my development site. Remember to always backup your database.

[To manually delete a content type that was created by a feature](https://www.drupal.org/node/1055460) #16 what  [Nedjo](https://www.drupal.org/u/nedjo) suggests is the following:

> - Disable the feature. I've sometimes run into problems with this--a feature won't disable. In this case, remove the feature module code.
> - Determine the machine name of the content type to be deleted, e.g., 'mytype'.
> - In the database, revert the node_type table values to the defaults as if the content type were created manually through the UI:
>
> `mysql> UPDATE node_type SET module = 'node', custom = 1, modified =
>   1, locked = 0 WHERE type = 'mytype';`
>
> - Clear caches to ensure the content type change is available.
> - Through the UI at admin/structure/types, delete the content type.

Answer (score 0):

If you use [admin_menu module](https://www.drupal.org/project/admin_menu), you will still see the delete links in pull-down menu Structure / Content types / [content type name] / Delete, even if they are not displayed on the content types page.

I would say it's pretty safe to use this delete link if you assure there are no other references to this content type anymore.